# sqlite copy values within a table

Tags: sqlite

I'm completely new to sqlite, so bear with me. I am updating a database and need to copy values within the same table, named "custom". I used pragma to get the table info, it's:

> 0|ticket|integer|0||0
>
> 1|name|text|0||0
>
> 2|value|0||0

Using `select * from custom where ticket = (some value)` I get, among other results,

> (some value)|block|
>
> (some value)|required|(another value)

I want to copy (another value) to "block" anywhere this value exists in "required". How do I make that happen? Everything I've tried has failed miserably to this point.

My pseudo code version would be something like

```
update custom

where required has a value

copy it to block
```

How do I turn that into actual sqlite commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE custom
SET value = (SELECT value
             FROM custom AS c2
             WHERE c2.ticket = custom.ticket
               AND c2.name = 'required')
WHERE name = 'block'
  AND value IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I did have to take out the last line as the value in 'block' was not null, but otherwise that did it. I'd upvote but I'm new, so I don't have enough reputation, apparently.